# Django haystack: elasticsearch how to delete by query

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

ElasticSearch offers a way to [`delete_by_query`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete_by_query) and I see that it is being called on the `clear` method of the backend with:

```
self.conn.delete_by_query(index=self.index_name, doc_type='modelresult', body=query)
```

where the `query` is something like this:

```
{'query': {'query_string': {'query': "Model1 OR Model2"}}}
```

Now, I don't know much about `ElasticSearch` and I created my Index like:

```
class MyIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    ...
    category = indexes.CharField(model_attr='category_id')
    ...
```

And now I want to delete from my index all the documents that match `category=5` and I tried something like:

```
backend.conn.delete_by_query(index='haystack', doc_type='modelresult', body= {'query': {'match': {'category': '5'}}})
```

and it outputs something like this:

> {'_version': 4, 'created': False, '_id': '_delete_by_query', '_index': 'haystack', '_type': 'modelresult', '_shards': {'successful': 1, 'failed': 0, 'total': 2}}

But it didn't delete it, I assume I need a better query, so what would it be? I also read that I can use the `bulk` method from `ElasticSearch`.

Btw I also checked that I can get a "query" from a `SearchQuerySet` instance with:

```
sqs.query.build_query()
```

that gives:

```
'category:(5)'
```

so it would be very helpful if I could use that `query` output for the `delete_by_query` method, but I don't know how to use it